# Matplotlib building on docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, docker

I have an application in Python that I want to create a docker image for. The application works fine on my PC but when I create a docker image I get this warning:

> UserWarning: Matplotlib is building the font cache using fc-list.
>   This may take a moment.   warnings.warn('Matplotlib is building the
>   font cache using fc-list. This may take a moment.')

After that I wait a little and the program crashes because there is a `float division by zero`. This never happens on the PC.

While testing it on my PC I have an environment active and I just `pip freeze > requirements.txt` so I know that everything is imported. I am using `matplotlib 1.5.3`.

I have seen the solutions to delete `~/.cache/matplotlib/fontList.cache` and `~/.matplotlib` but I cannot do that to a docker image.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I have a `Dockfile` and next to it a folder with my program (and some other files that I need), I start the program with `hello.py`. From `hello.py` I start a subprocess which uses matplotlib.

Dockfile:

```
FROM continuumio/anaconda:4.2.0
MAINTAINER Milos Radosavljevic "kemis93@gmail.com"
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential libblas-dev liblapack-dev
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
WORKDIR /charts
COPY charts/requirements.txt charts/
RUN pip install -r charts/requirements.txt
COPY charts /charts
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
CMD ["hello.py"]
EXPOSE 5000
```

requirements.txt:

```
click==6.6
cycler==0.10.0
DateTime==4.1.1
decorator==4.0.10
docutils==0.13.1
entrypoints==0.2.2
et-xmlfile==1.0.1
Flask==0.11.1
itsdangerous==0.24
jdcal==1.3
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
matplotlib==1.5.3
numexpr==2.6.1
numpy==1.11.2
openpyxl==2.4.1
pandas==0.19.1
pyparsing==2.1.10
python-dateutil==2.6.0
pytz==2016.10
scipy==0.18.1
seaborn==0.7.1
six==1.10.0
statistics==1.0.3.5
tables==3.3.0
Werkzeug==0.11.11
xlrd==1.0.0
zope.interface==4.3.3
```

Comment: Can you show the `Dockerfile` and `requirements.txt` files? which might help to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Rao I have added them

Comment: At least for the warning message, try adding "RUN python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot"" to your Dockerfile. It will only warn once when the docker is built then should stop thereafter. Not sure about your divide by zero bug.